# How to add my custom plugin? in Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created my own helloWorld plugin and added that into my ionic project. My problem is I'm not able to call that custom plugin can anyone elaborate me on this I have referred numerous articles but still I'm lagging in this step

I have created and integrated my plugin using this link

https://medium.com/@sangkhim/build-your-first-cordova-plugin-for-ionic-native-38d29a170145